# How to provide username password when using Restful api in java?

Tags: java, spring, restful-authentication

I have created basic authentication for a spring boot application which requires username and password.

Using it from browser works fine, with a popup asking for password

[image]

But how do I use it in a java application?(preferably using jackson 2 but other tools are fine). Searching online only shows about web based login pages.

Comment: http auth is considered not secure, probably that's why you can't find it

Comment: @OlegMikheev I am using https with a ssl certificate from Let's Encrypt? Is it still bad? In that case, what should I use?

Comment: Do you use xml configuration?

Comment: @PavloPlynko No. I plan to use plain java as far as possible

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Basic_Authentication
what to use depends on lots of things, normally you would have some service (may be part of our rest) that gets usrname/password and returns a (secure/encrypted) token that expires after some time... or better use OAuth2, but that's trickier... Spring Security should cover all that

Answer (score 1):

You need to set-up **Authorization** header to contain username and password in a proper Base64 encoded format to the http request you're making from the java application. Read section *client side* [from this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for details